# how can i break word in html or css?

Tags: html, css, word-break, css-hyphens

I'm trying to break the word at the end of the line like this **for example   "Lor-
em ipesm**" where I'm using **word-break:break** al but it can not add "-" it can do only **for example"Lor
em ipesm"**
how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `hyphens: auto`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Comment: There is a [Css hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `hyphens: auto` in your CSS.